# Accessing a stream inside a Nested StreamBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, rxdart

I am having an issue calling a StreamBuilder inside another StreamBuilder which is located inside the onPressed field of RasedButton widget. Basically, I am trying to access a stream (after adding data to it) inside the inner StreamBuilder, but the execution does not call this part of the code:

```
Widget submitButton(BuildContext ctx, AccountBloc bloc){
   return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.submitValid,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 60,
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: HexColor("0072b1"),
            child: Text("Sign in", style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.white
            ),
            ),
            onPressed:() {
               if(snapshot.hasData){
                 bloc.loginUser();
             
                 // DEBUGGING
                 print(bloc.isAuthenticated.listen((val) { print("debug isAuthenticated: $val"); }));
                  StreamBuilder(
                     stream: bloc.isAuthenticated,
                     builder: (ctx, snapshotA){
                       print("here");
                       if(!snapshotA.hasData){
                         return Text("loading....");
                       }
                       print("***${snapshotA.data}****");
                       if(snapshotA.data == false){
                         return navSignUpScreen(ctx);
                       }else if (snapshotA.data == false){
                         print("here");
                         return navHomeScreen(ctx);
                       }
                       return navSignUpScreen(ctx);
                     }
                 );
               }
            },
          ),
        );
      }
  );
}
```

The BLOC part is as follows:

```
  final _isAuthenticated = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  Stream<bool> get isAuthenticated => _isAuthenticated.stream;

  void loginUser() async {
    var inMemory = InMemoryProvider();
    inMemory.newInMemoryProvider();

    UserModel userResult = await _repository.loginUser(_email.value, _password.value);
    if(userResult.status == 200){
      // save TOKEN
      UserModel userModel = UserModel.fromJsonToModel(userResult.data);
      bool res =  await inMemory.store(userModel.id, userModel.token);
      _isAuthenticated.sink.add(res);
    }
    _userLoginResponse.sink.add(userResult);
  }
```

The navHomeScreen definition is as simple as this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}


class HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    AllReportsScreen(), UserProfileScreen()
  ];

  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: mainBottomNavigatorBar(),
    );
  }

  Widget mainBottomNavigatorBar() {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      onTap: onTabTapped,
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,

      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
          icon: new Icon(Icons.note),
          title: new Text('Reports', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
          icon: new Icon(Icons.label_important),
          title: new Text('Attention', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
          icon: new Icon(Icons.person_pin),
          title: new Text('Profile', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }


  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: why are you returning a widget inside onPressed()? It does nothing

Comment: I am basically returning a class. Please, what is a better approach? Also, the concern is that the inner StreamBuilder does not run at all.

Comment: it definitely won't run at all. you cannot display widgets inside onPressed. What you can do instead is to place the Streambuilder below the streambuilder on top and have the bottom streambuilder display when you click on the streambuilder on top.

Comment: Thank you @Uni. But please could you share a code snippet of how it can be done? My understanding id that, moving the inner StreamBuilder right above the RaisedButton would not work either as I have tried that just now.

Comment: I don't have a code snippet on how its done but all I'm suggesting is that you have something like this: Column([StreamBuilder(),StreamBuilder(this streambuilder will display what you wanted when pressing the button)])

Comment: Oh, I understand your suggestion now. But the problem here is that the outer StreamBuilder has to operate on a Widget (in this case, the RaisedButton). In other words, it checks streams of data entering the Form fields and submits them. Moving the inner StreamBuilder upper will cause an issue here.

Comment: In addition, the inner StreamBuilder is meant to be called upon a click on a button. Which means it needs to be called inside the onPressed field of the RaisedButton. Except I am missing something.

Comment: If that's the case, why are you using Streambuilder to execute functions? You can execute your functions using listeners

Comment: The problem is that the inner StreamBuilder itself does not get called. Using a StreamBuilder is already listening for stream of data. I do not see why that is an issue.

Comment: the inner streambuilder doesn't get called because its a widget. You aren't suppose to have widgets inside functions to execute your functions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @Uni. I solved this problem by getting rid of the inner StreamBuilder, and simply listen to the "isAuthenticated" bloc method inside the onPressed body. This is neat and works well. Now, I need to worry about error messages in case there any. But I am good now.

Answer (score 0):

Using `combineLatest` from `rxdart` to combine two `Stream`s `isAuthenticated` and `submitValid` into one `Stream`:

```dart
class LoginState {
    final bool isAuthenticated;
    final bool submitValid;
}

final state$ = Rx.combineLatest(
    bloc.isAuthenticated,
    bloc.submitValid,
    (isAuth, valid) => LoginState(isAuth, valid),
);

StreamBuilder<LoginState>(
    stream: state$,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final state = snapshot.data;
        if (state == null) return ...;
        if (!state.submitValid) return ...;
        if (state.isAuthenticated) return ...;
    }
)
```